# SharePoint:People Picker is not working inside the Ajax TabPanel

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any resolution to use SharePoint:PeoplePicker Inside the Ajax TabPanel? I am developing visual webpart for making Form and form have many tabs, so i need SharePoint:PeoplePicker inside the Panel.

Thanks in advance, if any one know how it is possible

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in MOSS 2007 and [SmartPart](http://smartpart.codeplex.com/)(visual webpart equivalent in 2007) to place a people picker control in a ajax panel

1) Place a ajax panel on aspx page (updatepanel or other similar controls)
2) Create a peoplepicker control in the page load event in the code behind. Use Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor class.
An example in vb.net:

```
 objEditorSearchHistory = New PeopleEditor()
 objEditorSearchHistory.PlaceButtonsUnderEntityEditor = True
 objEditorSearchHistory.ID = "pplEditorSearchHistory"
 objEditorSearchHistory.AllowEmpty = False
 objEditorSearchHistory.SelectionSet = "User,SecGroup,SPGroup"
 objEditorSearchHistory.MultiSelect = False
 objEditorSearchHistory.Width = Unit.Pixel(150)
```

3) Add the people picker control to the panel (panel.controls.Add(people picker)